# Machine Learning: What is the best algorithm to select best 3 variable combinations?

Tags: machine-learning, montecarlo, monte-carlo-tree-search

I have 10 variables as like below

> V1=1, V2=2, V3=3, V4=4, V5=5, V6=6, V7=7, V8=8, V9=9 and V10=10

***Note : Each variable can have any value***

Now I want to select the best 3 variables combination as like below

> V1V3V4 or V10V1V7 or V5V3V9 etc.

The best combination is nothing but the sum of 3 variables in the combination.

***Example:***

> Combination 1(V1V2V3) : 1+2+3=> **6**
>
> Combination 2(V8V9V10) : 8+9+10=> **27**

In the above example **Combination 2(V8V9V10)** has the highest sum value. So the **Combination 2(V8V9V10)** is the best combination here.

Like this if I have large amount of variables means which machine learning algorithm selects the best combination in all the sense.

Suggest me the best machine learning algorithm for selecting the best variable combinations. Thanks in advance.

Note: I think **Monte Carlo Algorithm** is one of the algorithm for this scenario up to my knowledge. But I need best algorithm compare to Monte Carlo Algorithm.

Comment: Maybe ask in ai.stackexchange.com/ if you have no luck here

Comment: What do you mean by best 3 list combinations ? best upon which attributes ? To get some help, please show us what you tried so far !

Answer (score 0):

There is more eloboration is required to your question. You have mentioned group names and patterns which you would like to achieve. However, bear in mind that these 3 lists/cluster combinations has to be performed based on certain data and their relevant attributes.
Once you provide details on either data, their pattern you would also need to explain what is your desired output from this list.
Based on clear expectation, suitable ML algorithm (One ore group of ML) need to be identified and tried to achieve better and optimized result.Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks to (Jessica Chambers, Pierre-Nicolas Piquin and Atul Kumar) for your responses. As per your suggestion I modified my question. Please go through my modified question and guide me. Thanks.